# How to compile a C++0x code on Eclipse CDT on mac?

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, c++11

Can someone point to flags and setup changes required for one to compile C++0x code on a Eclipse CDT on mac please ?

Comment: @Mark, can you please tell me how do I find compiler version too ? :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest Apple gcc compiler is gcc 4.2 which does not support C+11 code. You need to install a gcc 4.6 - this can be done from source or there are some binaries at [hpc](http://hpc.sourceforge.net/) this put the gcc in /usr/local/bin Then use that in the preferences fot the C++ compiler in eclipse.

Alternative for Lion and above Xcode 4.* includes clang the latest version of which doies much of C+11

If you want a later gcc macports (and fink and homebrew) have a later version as a port. As of July 2012 macports has 4.7.1 and a 4.8 beta. The package managers are often the easiest way to get complex compiled code onto your machine and they also have centrally compiled versions that will be downloaded by default.

Comment: You could also use macports (http://www.macports.org/) and compile a later version of GCC using it. GCC 4.6 beta is available :)

Comment: I would normally suggest macports but in this case gcc46 is a 4.6.0 beta and 4.6.1 has been released

Comment: Ahh, makes sense ;) Macports is behind!

Answer (score 6):

To use C++0x in Eclipse CDT on OSX (in a managed make project):

- Open the project properties
- C/C++ Build
- Settings
- Change the "Command" field in "MacOS X C++ Linker" and in "GCC G++ Compiler" from g++ to c++ (before check that c++ is clang++ with "c++ --version" in a shell)
- Add "-std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++" in the "Miscellaneous" parameters of "GCC G++ Compiler"
- Add "-stdlib=libc++" in the MIscellaneous "Linker flags" parameters of "MacOS X C++ Linker"
- Open the "Discovery options", select the "GCC C++ compile" change g++ to c++ and add -std=c++0x to the "Compiler invocation arguments"
- Add "/usr/include/c++/v1" to the "includes" in "Paths and Symbols" in C/C++ General

Comment: Works like a charm, even the editor recognizes the types. I prefer this method over installing Gcc via MacPorts.

Comment: Compile and run success,  but eclipse have some error in the IDE when edit code.  
Method 'cbegin' could not be resolved test.cpp /test/src line 18 Semantic Error

Comment: This is my code:
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
v.cbegin();

Comment: With XCode 4.5.2 add /usr/lib/c++/v1 to the includes in "Paths and Symbols" in C/C++ General. You can use also -std=c++11 instead of -std=c++0x (check that clang is 4.1 with c++ --version)