# Eclipse, Macos 10.8 and C++11

Tags: eclipse, macos, c++11

I'm trying to use C++11 but eclipse is having some trouble with it. I've used macports to get gcc48, and I've followed various guides for getting eclipse to use the new compiler, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870257/eclipse-will-not-use-gcc-4-7-on-mac), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support), 
and I've also changed the compiler command from the eclipse standard to the g++-mp-4.8 as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014484/how-to-set-eclipse-cdt-to-use-gcc-4-instead-of-gcc)

I am trying to build the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
 #include<memory>
using namespace std;
int main() {
std::unique_ptr<double> ptr(new double);
*ptr = 11.345;

cout << (*ptr) << endl;

return 0;
}
```

The terminal will compile this fine,

```
make all 
Building file: ../src/C++11.cpp
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
/opt/local/bin/g++ -I/opt/local/bin -I/opt/local/include -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x -MMD -MP -MF"src/C++11.d" -MT"src/C++11.d" -o "src/C++11.o" "../src/C++11.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/C++11.cpp

Building target: C++11
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
g++  -o "C++11"  ./src/C++11.o   
Finished building target: C++11
```

and the program runs just as expected. However, in eclipse, I still get the error message `Symbol 'unique_ptr' could not be resolved`.

I would like to continue using eclipse as more than just a project manager and makefile builder, so any help on this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using g++, one can use clang++. I used the answers [Error when compiling some simple c++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533321/error-when-compiling-some-simple-c-code), [clang 3.1 can't see unique_ptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853822/clang-3-1-cant-see-unique-ptr) and [How to compile a C++0x code on Eclipse CDT on mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302692/how-to-compile-a-c0x-code-on-eclipse-cdt-on-mac) as guides to come up with the following steps:

1. change the compiler in the Project->Properties->C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Gcc C++ Compiler -> Command (change g++ to clang++).
2. in Project->Properties->C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Gcc C++ Compiler -> Miscellaneous, append `-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++` to the flags.
3. do the same as one for the linker under C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Gcc C++ Linker -> Command
4. in Properties->C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Gcc C++ Linker -> Miscellaneous, add `-stdlib=libc++` to the Linker flags.
5. in Properties->C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros,etc -> Providers -> CDT GCC Builtin Compiler Settings, turn off the Share option, and append `-std=c++11` to the Command to get compiler specs.

The compilation works perfectly and the program runs well. That eclipse doesn't recognize the smart pointer appears to be a bug: see [Turn off eclipse errors (that arent really errors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131939/turn-off-eclipse-errors-that-arent-really-errors)