# Error with new gcc48 on macos

Tags: macos, gcc, compilation, macports

I'm having serious problems running some standard commands such as sleep() with g++-mp-4.8 downloaded from macports. I don't have any of these problems compiling with llvm-g++-4.2.

This is quite annoying, because I'm trying to use C++11 features in this program.

Here is the read out from the compiler - I'm really sorry it's so long, I just have no idea what to do with it:

```
17:11:54 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project BSDESimV2 ****
make all 
Building file: ../TrueSolutions/TrueSoln.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
/opt/local/bin/g++ -g -O0 -Wall -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 /lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/include -I/usr/include/c++/4.2.1 -I/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backup -I/opt/local/bin -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"TrueSolutions/TrueSoln.d" -MT"TrueSolutions/TrueSoln.d" -o "TrueSolutions/TrueSoln.o" "../TrueSolutions/TrueSoln.cpp"
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:72:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/char_traits.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ios:45,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/istream:44,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/fstream:45,
                 from ../TrueSolutions/TrueSoln.h:15,
                 from ../TrueSolutions/TrueSoln.cpp:8:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:381:12: error: expected identifier before '__is_pod'
     struct __is_pod
        ^
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:381:12: error: expected unqualified-id before '__is_pod'
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:394:12: error: expected identifier before '__is_empty'
     struct __is_empty
        ^
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:394:12: error: expected unqualified-id before '__is_empty'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/memory:54:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/string:48,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/locale_classes.h:47,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/ios_base.h:47,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ios:48,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/istream:44,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/fstream:45,
                 from ../TrueSolutions/TrueSoln.h:15,
                 from ../TrueSolutions/TrueSoln.cpp:8:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/allocator.h:135:41: error: expected unqualified-id before '__is_empty'
    template<typename _Alloc, bool = std::__is_empty<_Alloc>::__value>
                                     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/allocator.h:135:41: error: expected '>' before '__is_empty'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/vector:70:0,
                 from ../TrueSolutions/TrueSoln.h:23,
                 from ../TrueSolutions/TrueSoln.cpp:8:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_vector.h: In member function 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::swap(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&)':
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_vector.h:740:34: error: template argument 2 is invalid
  std::__alloc_swap<_Tp_alloc_type>::_S_do_it(_M_get_Tp_allocator(),
                              ^
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_vector.h:740:45: error: invalid type in declaration before '(' token
  std::__alloc_swap<_Tp_alloc_type>::_S_do_it(_M_get_Tp_allocator(),
                                         ^
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_vector.h:741:36: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
           __x._M_get_Tp_allocator());
                                ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/vector:71:0,
                 from ../TrueSolutions/TrueSoln.h:23,
             from ../TrueSolutions/TrueSoln.cpp:8:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_bvector.h: In member function 'void std::vector<bool, _Alloc>::swap(std::vector<bool, _Alloc>&)':
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_bvector.h:690:56: error: template argument 2 is invalid
       std::__alloc_swap<typename _Base::_Bit_alloc_type>::
                                                    ^
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_bvector.h:691:10: error: invalid type in declaration before '(' token
  _S_do_it(_M_get_Bit_allocator(), __x._M_get_Bit_allocator());
      ^
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_bvector.h:691:61: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
  _S_do_it(_M_get_Bit_allocator(), __x._M_get_Bit_allocator());
                                                         ^
make: *** [TrueSolutions/TrueSoln.o] Error 1
```

Comment: I also can't get it to work with gcc46

Comment: Why are all those `-I` flags being used?

Comment: There is some functionality I cannot regain if I remove the -I/usr/... flags. I think the problem is library consistency between the gcc versions, but I don't know what headers I should include to get around it.

Comment: Have you tried removing all the `-I` flags?  Also have you tried installing the Xcode command line tools and using `clang` instead?

Comment: Thanks! that solved it. I already had command line tools, actually. Clang let me get rid of all the -I's just fine :) I don't know how this works, shall I put the answer up or would you like to?

Comment: You do it; I'm not sure I added much value :)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the hints, I got rid of all the outdated `-I/`'s and set up the `clang++` compiler as in [Eclipse, Macos 10.8 and C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550450/eclipse-macos-10-8-and-c11/17570792#17570792)

There were some clashes with between my code and the stl, but they were easy to hunt down from the console output.