# Updating gcc on osx 10.8

Tags: macos, gcc, libraries, updates

I'm C++ programming and I've been working with llvm-gcc42 up till now. I want to switch to gcc46 or later. Are there any particular headers I need to include to make this transition smooth?

Thanks for your help!

PS Sorry about repeated posts on this topic. I think this is the simplest and most general formulation I could come up with. For detailed error messages I've been getting, please see [Error with new gcc48 on macos](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17552083/2500952)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using clang with OS X. Otherwise you can install gcc-4.8.1 with [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/) or [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/). *Don't* try updating or replacing the 'system' compilers (bundled with Xcode) manually. You can search previous questions on the details for using these port systems.